# How to retrieve text of li tag for each associated checkbox using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I created group of list and checkbox dynamically using php, for each li tag I associated a checkbox, my problem is I can't display value of each li tag when I click its associated checkbox. When I click on each generated checkbox, I got texts of all "li" tag. Can you help me please?
Here is my code:

```js
echo '<ul>';
while ($row2 = pg_fetch_array($result2)) 
{
              

 echo '<div class="col-sm-10"><li class="Liste">' . $row2['nom'] . '</li>       <div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="DisplayCheckbox" value=""></label>
  </div></div><br />';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

in the same php file I added this jquery code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

         
    var itemValue= [];
        $('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]').on('click',function()
        {
          if($(this).is(":checked"))
          {

                
           listeItem = $(this).parents("div").find(".Liste").text();
               alert(listeItem);
              
          }
            

        });
        
    
});
        
</script>
```

Comment: `Id` should be unique....I think you can use a class instead, like `<input type="checkbox" class="DisplayCheckbox" value="">`

Comment: I did what you said baut I got the same result, it display all text list for each checkbox, but I want to display fot each checkbox its associated text "li" tag

Comment: Yeah but now you need to update your jquery code..just change this `$('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]')` to this `$('.DisplayCheckbox')`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `parents()` looks through all the ancestors of the element you're referencing. For instance, you should add a unique id to each div containing the `li` and the checkbox.

Try:

```
echo '<ul>';
while ($row2 = pg_fetch_array($result2)) 
{


 echo '<div id="' . $row['nom'] . '" class="col-sm-10"><li class="Liste">' . $row2['nom'] . '</li>       <div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="DisplayCheckbox" value=""><input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row['nom'] . '"></label>
  </div></div><br />';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

And:

```
$('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]').on('click',function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                parent = $(this).next('input[name="id"]').val();
                listeItem = $(this).parents('#' + parent).find(".Liste").text();
                alert(listeItem);
            }
});
```

Comment: Very nice Condorcho , it's working, but I don't understand why you add hidden input? Can you please explain to me?

Comment: Basically so you can get the id you are looking for inside jQuery, in case you have the jQuery script in another file.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm trying to understand your code :)

Comment: Instead of adding hidden input, I add name and value for input checkbox like that: <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="DisplayCheckbox" value="' . $row2['nom'] . '">, and in js code I do: $('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]').on('click',function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                parent = $(this).val();
                listeItem = $(this).parents('#' + parent).find(".Liste").text();
                alert(listeItem);
            }});

Comment: It's working but I want to know if it's a good solution or not? Thank you

Comment: I want to complete this code, so I add a hidden input where I put data as result of a query, I want to display this data associated on each checkbox(the same checkboxes in the post), I tried to do that but it's not working. Here is my code php: while($row=pg_fetch_array($result)) 
 {echo '<input type="hidden" class="Geom" id="' . $row[0] .'"name="id" value="' . $row[0] . '">';}. Js code: 
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {next = $( ".Geom" ).val();
             CoordItem = $('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]').next('#'    next).text();
                alert(CoordItem); }

Comment: I got a syntax error: "Syntax error, unrecognized expression:.....". Can you help me, please?

Comment: Yes, the first solution you gave me using `name` attribute is better than adding a hidden input. When you add an input field you're sending more data in the request.